Why is $\frac{d}{dx}\int^x_1 \frac{dt}{t}$ is different from $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x)$?
Why is $\frac{d}{dx}{\displaystyle \int^x_1} \frac{dt}{t}$ is different from $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x)$ ?
Even though
$$\int^x_1\frac{dt}{t} = \ln(x). $$
Plotting both on Desmos, I noticed that
$$\frac{d}{dx}{\int^x_1} \frac{dt}{t} = \frac{1}{x} \qquad (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*), $$
but
$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x) = \frac{1}{x} \qquad (\text{only }\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*_+). $$
How does the derivative of the same thing can give two different results?

How do you define the integral for $x<0$?

When $x\le0$, $\int_1^x \dfrac 1t dt$ is undefined as it involves infinity.

The function $log(x)$ is not defined for $x<0$.

For $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t}$, if you have an option to specify Prinicipal Value, you might get the same result as $\frac{d}{dx} \log(x)$. In mathematica, the following code works: D[Integrate[1/t,{t,1,x},PrincipalValue->True],x]. It gives $\frac{1}{x}$

Please stop with the needless rollbacks. Your initial rendering of the LaTeX is in bad form and looks wrong (e.g. unnecessary use of \displaystyle, $ln(x)$ versus $\ln(x)$ - the former looking much worse - typing text in math environments, several grammatical errors, and so on).

Note that you do have $\frac{d}{dx}\ln |x| = \frac{1}{x} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^\ast$ (using absolute value signs). The same also holds for $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(|x|) + C(x)$ where $C(x) = C_1$ when $x \lt 0$ and $C_2$ when $x \gt 0$ for any constants $C_1, C_2$.

This have a simple explanation: Desmos doesn't have a brain. Always keep this in mind when using mathematical software.

I imagine what's going on here is that Desmos is using some implementation of the fundamental theorem of calculus, so
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_a^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = f(x)
$$
Luckily,
$$
f(x) = \frac 1 x
$$
is defined on all $x \ne 0$. On the other hand, $\ln(x)$ is only defined (on the reals) when $x>0$, and naturally a function cannot have a derivative where it is not defined (since the limit definition becomes total nonsense there).

Relevant.

The fundamental theorem of calculus is true for $f$ continuous on an interval, which is not the case of the inverse function on $\Bbb R^*$, so Desmos just goes wrong
